# How to resolve "shift: can't shift that many" error while running a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, jmeter, scripting-language

I have a shell script with different methods.The script is

```
    status(){
    PID=$(ps -ef | grep jmeter_script.sh|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}')
    }

    start(){
    shift
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
            exit 1;
    fi
    jmeter.sh -n -t "$1"  -l "$2"
    }

    stop(){
        while true; do
            read -p "Do you really want to stop?" yn
            case $yn in
                [Yy]* ) ps -ef | grep jmeter | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill; break;;
                [Nn]* ) exit;;
                * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
            esac
view(){
#some code
}

    ####Main
    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case "$1" in
            start )
                start
                ;;

            stop)
                stop
                ;;

            status)
                status
                ;;
            view)
                view
                ;;
            *)
                echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|view}"
                exit 1
            esac
        shift
    done
```

When I try to run the script using `./jmeter_script.sh start abc.jmx log.jtl` I get an error saying `./jmeter_script.sh: 19: shift: can't shift that many` and then exit. I am running my script on `ubuntu` server. I have tried to resolve this but I ddin't find any proper link for this error. Someone please help.

Comment: You can't shift by more than `$#`.  When `$#` is 0 (as in the invocation of `start`), you can't use `shift` at all.  Inside a function, `"$@"` etc are the arguments to the function call, not to the script as a whole.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How do I fix that? How can I change the `if condition` in the `start()` method? or How can I change the `start()` method so that it should take the `command line arguments`.

Comment: @Cyrus I didn't get what you said. Can you please explain where I went wrong

Comment: You probably don't; you call `start arg1 arg2 arg3` so that you can shift `arg1` out of the way and then use `$1` and `$2`.  Of course, there's the question of why you pass the original `$1` (`arg1` in my outline call) if you're only going to ignore it — but you can probably figure that out for yourself.

Comment: @user6348718: I was wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am new to shell scripting. I have tried to resolve it but I didn't understand. Can you please help?

Comment: Your `start` function runs: `jmeter.sh -n -t "$1"  -l "$2"`.  That means that you need to execute `start something what-goes-in-dollar-1 what-goes-in-dollar-2`.  There's no indication whatsoever of how this script as a whole might be intended to be used.  Maybe you run `your-script start 1000 20` and your intention is that it should run `jmeter.sh -n -t "1000"  -l "20"`?  You've not said, so we can't tell for sure.  It also seems like you might be able to run `your-script stop view status start 1000 20 stop` and maybe you'd be stopping, viewing, statusing, starting and stopping.

Comment: The $# and the positional parameters are scoped to the function. You're calling start with no arguments so $# is 0. Try calling `start "$@"` instead.

Comment: BTW, note that parsing `ps` output is generally a serious code smell. On modern Ubuntu you should be using `systemctl` to start, stop, check the status of, and otherwise manage services.

Answer (score 1):

Those are functions, not methods.  Don't go overboard applying OOD terminology where it doesn't begin to apply.

The best way to avoid shift errors is not to shift when you have run out of arguments.  Check the value of $# **BEFORE** you shift.

It would be easier to parse your ps -ef output if you don't specify lots of flags.  All you need is PID and PNAME.

Answer (score 1):

A safe shift way: `shift $(( 3 > $# ? $# : 3))`
In this case i try to shift 3 positions, if the count was les of that, I just shift the max.